# Изменение отображения ссылки на изображение из ImageField

Tags: django, forms

```
<pre>
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
</pre>
```

По умолчанию Django выводит field изображения как ссылку, текст является копией названия изображения. Как можно поменять отображаемый текст, то есть Мое название?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for field in form %}
    <img src="{{ field.url }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]